# Get localized string resources before run (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to get localized string resources before run (C# Winforms). I have custom control of button with printing text on event OnPaint. I can set culture for set location before running in the constractor of custom control and see erea for text in designer:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

But when I try to get string resource before running I get neutral string resource instead of the German:

```
ResourceManager p = new ResourceManager("myProject.Properties.Resources", 
                                        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
Text = p.GetString(ResourceNameForText, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

How can I get the German string resurce in designer before running?

Comment: When is before running? Do you need to show "de-DE" text at  design-time?

Comment: Yes, I do. I want have design-time tooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a solution. We have created an open property in custom control, which calls stream reading and parsing method from Resources.de-DE.resx during design-time mode only.

Comment: I cannot attach code because this is part of comersial project. But you can define disign-time using class System.ComponentModel.DesignMode and use feature public properties of user control whitch return get method in a property even in design-time. So you can call some method from get method in a property for parsing file Resources.de-DE.resx using XElement or regular expression. For define path you can use interface DTE.